# Running android e2e tests on circleci 2.0 using detox for react native

Tags: android, react-native, e2e-testing, detox, circleci-2.0

I am doing detox android e2e on circleci(2.0) and facing two issues -

1. circle ci (2) still does not support x86 bases emulators, so I am using ARM based ems
2. Its really slow, detox hits a timeout before even the emulator starts / app gets installed, so firebase test lab comes into picture

Is there a way to run android x86 emulators on circleci 2? and
Does Detox support running tests on firebase test lab? Is there any documentation around it?

For reference, here is my yaml file for circleci

```
    reference:
      android_config: &android_config
        docker:
          - image: circleci/android:api-28-node8-alpha
      download_android_dependencies: &download_android_dependencies
        run:
          name: Download Android Dependencies
          command: |
            ls
            cd android
            ./gradlew androidDependencies
            cd ../
    jobs:
      test-android:
        <<: *android_config
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: npm install
        - *download_android_dependencies
        - run: sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
        - run: sdkmanager --licenses
        - run: echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n testEmulator -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
        - run:
              name: Run emulator in background
              command: |
                sudo apt-get install libpulse0
                export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${ANDROID_HOME}
                export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib emulator64-arm -avd testEmulator -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel on -verbose -gpu swiftshader
               background: true
         - run: sudo npm install -g detox-cli
         - run:
              name: start pkg server
              command: npm start
              background: true
          - run: detox build -c android.emu.debug
          - run: detox test -c android.emu.debug -l trace
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - test-android
```

Comment: Hey - did you ever get anywhere with this? I am interested in using CurcleCI or detox (probably on iOS though)

Comment: We have migrated from circleci to bitrise now, which has support for running android x86 emulators, but its still flaky. It hits timeout sometimes. For IOS, it was working properly on circle ci and its working properly on bitrise as well. Its little slow, but its working.